# Linq to Sql issue with Long DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

Problem:  Sql dateTime column which contains legacy data that has time constraints against it.  I have an MVC form with Date selector to allow users to select a date and bring all records back from DB that has that date.

Issue I have however is that the linq to sql is literal to the data model and I cannot cast the datetime colum to date only for the comparison.  heres a code snippet

myDateSelected = 27/01/2011
p.PostedDate in database would equal something like 27/01/2001 17:09:00

```
var p from products
where p.PostedDate == myDateSelected
select p
```

How can I cast `p.PostedDate` to strip the time element off to allow for the compare to work?

pretty new to Linq and so far cannot find solution to my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming that p.PostedDate is a DateTime object.  If that is true, this should do it.

```
var p from products
where p.PostedDate.Date == myDateSelected
select p
```

Comment: to be sure you might want to have both sides stripped to Date, just in case:  var p from products
where p.PostedDate.Date == myDateSelected.Date
select p

Comment: Yes PostedDate is DateTime.  Doh ! Thanks Becuzz. (and indeed @ K Ivanov).

Answer (score 2):

You can call [`DateTime.Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) to truncate the time element, and LINQ-to-SQL will translate that to SQL for you:

```
var p from products
where p.PostedDate.Date == myDateSelected
select p
```

will get translated to something like this:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 DateTime = '2010-02-24 00:00:00.000'
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[PostedDate]
FROM [Products] AS [t0]
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, [t0].[PostedDate]) = @p0
```